# How can I diagnose my headlight wiring issue? 2003 Honda civic si

Tags: honda, electrical, civic, headlight

So I was upgrading my HID lights to LED, but I had to change one of the socket wiring harnesses. I asked for my friends help with rewiring,   because i wasnt sure which wires went where...so he looked some stuff up and helped me replace the socket. At first, it worked, but when using the high beam, it turned the lights off completely. I was convinced that it was a wiring issue so I did what I should have done at first and took the old socket apart to see which wires go where, and found out it wasn't connected right.

I then rewired it again, to mimic the old socket, and when I fired it up this time, no lights work at all. I am positive it's wired correctly, and I also checked the under-hood fuse box and the fuses looked fine for both the left and right headlight.

Then I noticed, one of the headlight fuses seemed to control both headlights, and the other one didn't seem to control anything.  the odd thing is that if I plug my good HID bulb in, it works, high and low beam, but it also has it's own custom wiring and does not use the OEM socket.  I just want my OEM sockets working again so I can use these LEDs, but it seems like I may have a wiring issue.

I have uploaded some images to imgur since they are apparently too large to upload here. If any other information or pictures are needed please let me know. Thanks!

https://imgur.com/gallery/Mdypz

Comment: Does the car have DRL and is it a hatchback? Do you have a multimeter? Can you be more specific about which fuses you checked and whether there was voltage drop across the fuse? Just because they look good doesn't mean power is going to them or across them. Based on the wiring I'm assuming you don't have DRL. In the second picture what is your connector going to? Is that the right side socket? Red/Wht, Red/Blu and Red? Red is fused B+, Red/Blu is  High beam, Red/Wht is low beam.

Comment: No, it doesn't have DRL, and yes it's a hatchback sorry. I'm about to go buy a multimeter right now. Also, I didn't just look at the fuses, there were some 15A fuses in the spare fuse area of the fusebox as well, although I haven't tried using brand new fuses. And yes, it's the right side (passenger), and those are the wire colors yes. But I have spliced the wires on the new socket to mimic their location on the old one.

Comment: Well if you can confirm that the wiring up to the socket functions as intended than that suggests something is wrong with your led setup. Have you tried installing a halogen bulb?

Comment: I have not, I didn't want to waste 15-20 dollars on a guess. I've been a bit busy today but I'm gonna give a more in depth check with this multimeter. I checked last night but I only checked with low beams on and I forgot to write down which circuits had voltage. I did however notice that with only the low beams on, there were 2 different combinations that gave a reading of 12 volts, which seems wrong, since only one of the combinations should have voltage if it was wired properly right? I'll post my findings tomorrow.

Comment: Well, I tested the sockets with the multimeter, and they seemed to be fine. But I also tested the bulbs on the battery itself, and they seem fine too. At this point, I'm just gonna go return the LED bulbs because they aren't working for me, but they seem like they are fine, as does the wiring.... so I'm at a loss here. I guess I'll just replace the HID bulb and call it a day, because I can't afford to pay someone to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: What combinations give voltage?

Comment: The wiring was right apparently, I just didn't have the right type of lights. I needed to get lights that support a CAN bus.

Answer (score 1):

Wow I feel dumb. Apparently my car needed lights with a CAN bus. I came to the conclusion that the wiring was okay, so I brought it back to the stereo shop... they messed with it for a bit until they realized my problem, and exchanged the new lights with me.

Answer (score 0):

The answers lie in your question. 3 fuses for the headlights. One for low beams. One for the high beams. The last one I suspect is for your daylight running lights which are activated by releasing the parking brake. When parking brake is activated with engine off no power to that circuit. I did a quick google search about Honda Civic headlight wiring.

Left Headlight 
High - RED/GRN

Low - RED/YEL

Ground - BLK

Right Headlight

High - RED/BLU

Low - RED/WHT

Ground - BLK

Comment: Well there's definitely no red/green wire, but I did also notice that the wire colors had 1 different wire color between the 2 sides. The passenger (right) was red/blue red/white and solid red. The driver side was red/white, red/blue and red/yellow.

Either way, I took the old socket apart to see which wire went to what part of the socket, and I mimicked it exactly. According to the fuse box diagrams in my car both under the hood and inside the car, there was a left and right headlight fuse under the hood and 2 different running light fuses inside the car. I checked them all and they were ok